# Java downloader removes digital certificate from signed exe

Tags: java, digital-certificate

I am working on java downloader which pulls files from remote server and saves them locally.

Here is the code I use:

```
try {

    BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new URL(link).openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;

        while( (count = in.read(data,0,1024)) != -1){
        bout.write(data,0,count);
        }

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    fos.close();


    } catch(Throwable t){
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

First thing I noticted, file on server and downloaded file aren't exact same size --> http://puu.sh/jGpEj/abbe832796.png (downloaded file is few bytes smaller). Notice that "size on the disk" appears to be same.

Next thing I noticted, if I try to run .exe downloaded by java "as administrator" it will say "Publisher: Unknown" which is not correct because .exe is digitally signed. Neither "Digital Signatures" tab is present.

Any clue what issue could be?

P.S I opened both files with Hex editor..they both seem to have same contents, except file downloaded by java is missing last 94 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing to a `BufferedOutputStream`, but you're flushing one of the downstream streams.  In other words, you're calling `flush()` on the wrong stream.

Flush the `BufferedOutputStream bout` instead:

```
try {
  BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new URL(link).openStream());
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
  BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);

  byte data[] = new byte[1024];
  int count;

  while( (count = in.read(data,0,1024)) != -1){
    bout.write(data,0,count);
  }

  bout.flush();
  bout.close();

  in.close();

} catch(Throwable t){
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should also `close` the `BufferedOutputStream` and it will automatically propagate the close down the underlying streams.  In other words, you don't close the `FileOutputStream` directly.

Finally, there's actually no need to call `flush()` before `close()`, as doing a `close()` will automatically do a `flush()` anyway.

As an aside, if you use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block, you can have the compiler insert the closes for you.